# Moving Input text value to an other with custom focus button when pressed to next focus

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have little code with custom 2 button which works such as tab or shift+tab on inputs.
My question is: how can I move input text value to next focus.

Example:

from:
[ Vegetable] <-- This an input 
[ Drinks(Focused)] <-- This an input
[           ] <-- This an input
[           ]

When Clicking next button it will be like this:

[ Vegetable]
[           ]
[ Drinks(Focused)]
[           ]

www.jsfiddle.net/xSDMy/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I modified your fiddle to a working state.  Though I recommend that you refactor your code to make it easier to read and maintain.

http://jsfiddle.net/xSDMy/3/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var $curr;

    $('.Tabbing').on('focus',function(){
      $curr = $(this);
    });

    $('.prevFocus, .nextFocus').on('click', function( e ){
      var inputElem = $curr.closest('li')[ $(this).hasClass("nextFocus") ? "next" :      "prev" ]('li').find('.Tabbing');
      var curVal = $curr.val();
      $curr.val("");

      inputElem.val(curVal);
      inputElem.focus();
    });
```

});